# Testing if shapefiles intersect from a list using intersect: ArcGIS

Tags: arcpy, intersection, basic-license-level, clip, statistics

I am new to programming and scripting in general, so please bear with me.  I have generated a list of the location of all the shapefiles for my workplace.  The files are all placed in folders, no geodatabases are used.  I am trying to create a tool which queries which of the shapefiles intersect another shapefile.  I would like to use the list as one of the inputs for the intersect parameters.  I want to:

1. Calculate the area of the intersected features
2. perform stats
3. If area of intersect > 0, convert the original data to feature layer
4. clip the feature layer and save as new fc in target location.

I would really appreciate some python script examples as to go about this task.

I am using arcGIS 10 with an arcView license.

Comment: When you say I'm new to programming, does that mean that you don't have any experience at all? Rather than write the script for you I can give you some pointers, but I need to know that you understand basic control structures and such.  An explanation of what you're trying to accomplish would be helpful; it seems like copying shapefiles that intersect into gdb is somewhat arbitrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was picking up Python for ArcGIS, I came across the PSU Master's in GIS Open Courseware.  [This particular lesson](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog485/node/130) covers spatial queries with feature layers.  I highly recommend the whole course, though, it covers syntax, loops, conditionals, functions, cursors, etc.

The courses also include exercises (with answers & video explanations) so you can practice using the queries and update attribute tables with cursors.

Comment: Thanks a lot Roy.  This is definitely something that can benefit me.